# Relation betwwen blood type and diet

Tags: diet, blood-type

Is there any scientific evidence for the relation between the blood type (0, A, B, AB) and digestion? Any correlation with natural food preference or recommended diet?

One can read about such "relations" in several books but their foundations are usually loose. For sure there must have been some scientific research done on that question.

Comment: One can read about such relations in what books? We can't respond to "I read it somewhere" questions. This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so please tell us specifically where you read this.

Comment: Also, questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here unless directly related to medical treatments, so this question is going to need to be more about blood types and digestion than about diet.